# Disable Enter Key to submit a form

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Im working with [jquery validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org), but if the all element is valid then i press enter, the form is submit, i want to submit form **ONLY** via **submit button** not with **enter key**, how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Enter key is the keydown number 13. You should use the following code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```